# Проблемы с виртуальной средой

Tags: python, django, deepin

Сделал виртуальную среду, активировал. Установил джанго, сделал `startproject`, но когда запускаю файл `manage.py` появляется ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to 
activate a virtual environment?`
```

До этого все работало нормально, проблем не возникало.
ОС - Linux Deepin

Comment: Давайте ваш полный алгоритм запуска manage.py начиная с запуска консоли

Comment: @andreymal [http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/S9tY]

Comment: Джанга точно устанавливалась именно в виртуальное окружение? А то что-то не похоже

Comment: В виртуальном окружении точно третий питон?

Comment: @andreymal да, при установке джанго использовался pip3

Comment: @andreymal и использовал `python3 -m venv`

Comment: Тогда фиг знает, у меня со всей этой последовательностью команд всё работает

Comment: @andreymal у меня тоже работало,
потом надо было сделать новую директорию. и вот такое,
уже пару раз переделывал

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install python3
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install django
django-admin startproject nameproject
python3 nameproject/manage.py runserver
```

Должно сработать